# Typescript class array assign by value

Tags: arrays, class, typescript

How to assign typescript class object array by value not by reference.
Below is the code

```
class Person {
    constructor(public Name: string, public Age: number) {
    }
}

let orignalArr: Person[] = [
    new Person('Gyan', 28),
    new Person('Parkash', 28),
];
let arr2 = orignalArr;    
//let arr2 = orignalArr.slice(0); i tried this but not working
arr2[0].Name = 'changed';
console.log(orignalArr);
//logs 0: Person {Name: "changed", Age: 28} 1: Person {Name: "Parkash", Age:
//  28}

console.log(arr2);
//logs 0: Person {Name: "changed", Age: 28} 1: Person {Name: "Parkash", Age:
//  28}
```

So what i need is the value of original array should not be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slice` will not work, because your items are also reference type and it will just return the copies of the references.

You can use `map` function to iterate over array items and then using `Object.assign`, you can copy the properties of each object into the new object.

The example is provided in Javascript.

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
    }
}

let originalArr = [
    new Person('Gyan', 28),
    new Person('Parkash', 28),
];

let arr2 = originalArr.map(item => Object.assign({}, item));
arr2[0].name = 'Changed';

console.log(originalArr[0]);
console.log(arr2[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks this is working, but i doubt it has impact on performance

Comment: You will not notice that impact